# Datagridview doesnt show any data

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, bindingsource

I am using a binding source control to load a datagridview in the winforms application. I load the binding source control with a list and the binding source as the datasource for the datagridview. when I run the code there is no data loaded in the datagridview. can anyone help me ? The code I wrote for this is given below.`

```
 private void SetData(ListAirport la, string iata)
    {
        itemBindingSource.DataSource = la;

        dgvItemDetails.DataSource = itemBindingSource;
    }
```

The Interesting thing is that, when I take itemBindingSource.Count, it shows 556 and dgvItemDetails.Rows.Count as 0

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    dgvItemDetails.DataSource = itemBindingSource;
    dgvItemDetails.DataBind();//You need to bind it to the control
```

Comment: ah my bad - misread, do you have dgvItemDetails.autogeneratecolumns=true?

Comment: I haven't touched it. Do I need to make it false ?

Comment: I'm not too experienced with winforms but if you want the columns to be genrated automatically have it set to true after setting the datasource, try here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Your DataGridView does not seem to know how to bind to a ListAirport. What you want to do is convert that to a DataTable.